# Get StringLength attribute from CodeProperty?

Tags: t4

I have created a set of T4 templates to generate the unit classes for a DAL. An issue I have is with providing a string of the correct length based on "StringLength" attribute on the properties of the entities.

I tried accessing CodeProperty.Attributes, but it says there are zero attributes where I know that to be incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this......

I was unable to utilize CodeProperty to obtain the attribute. Instead I use the following given I already have a CodeClass and CodeProperty to use in my search:

```
    private int GetStringLength(CodeProperty codeProperty, CodeClass codeClass)
     {
          var type = Type.GetType(codeClass.Name); //you may need to use assembly qualified name
          var props = type.GetProperties();

          if (props != null && props.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(codeProperty.Name)))
          {
               var matchingProperty = props.First(p => p.Name.Equals(codeProperty.Name);
               var strLenAttr = (StringLengthAttribute) matchingPropery.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
               if (strLenAttr == null) return 0;
               return strLenAttr.MaximumLength;
          }
          return 0;
     }
```